# Redirect theme directory to plugin theme directory

Tags: plugin-development, themes, filters

I want to activate a theme located in my plugin as the main theme.

```
/*
 * For directory structure like:
 * 
 * /my-plugin/
 * - /my-plugin.php
 * - /themes/
 *
 * 
 */
register_theme_directory( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/themes' );
```

What am I missing to then activate the theme on plugin activation?

https://codex.wordpress.org/register_theme_directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after tinkering a bit, I came up with 2 solutions..
Add into your main plugin init php file:

```php
$enable_theme = true; //conditional

if($enable_theme == true):
   register_theme_directory( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'themes' );
   switch_theme( 'mythemename'); // my custom template/stylesheet name
else:
   switch_theme( 'default'); // template/stylesheet name
endif;

/*** For Testing purposes ***/
//$current_theme = wp_get_theme();
//$name = $current_theme->get_stylesheet();
//$path = $current_theme->get_stylesheet_directory();
//echo $name;
//echo $path;
```

Or by using an WP action

```php
function updateTheme($theme){
        update_option('template', $theme);
        update_option('stylesheet', $theme);
        update_option('current_theme', $theme);
}

add_action( 'setup_theme', 'change_theme' );

function change_theme() {
  if($enable_theme == true):
    register_theme_directory( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'themes' );
    $theme = "mythemename";
  else:
    $theme = "default";
  endif;

        updateTheme($theme);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing everything. Themes are not plugins and should not depend on plugins being active. The admin user is the only one that should to activate whichever themes and plugins that he want in whatever order he want.

If your theme requires a plugin to operate you better distribute it as part of the theme

Comment: how I appreciate your expressions, I was wanting to still load a theme from a plugin.

Comment: let me try to say it differently, the system is not designed to work this way

Comment: If you haven't notice. Many new WP builders use this method to remove default themes and use their own using a plugin

Comment: @samjco not sure why you bring it after 4 years. that was true and wrong when you asked the question the first time.
Meanwhile there was gutenburg that killed separation of content and styling so maybe the discussion is pointless now.